# Algorithms in DHCP

Tags: algorithm, networking, ip, ip-address, dhcp

What are the algorithms that dictate how DHCP assigns IP addresses? Are there any references, algorithms, C/Assembly/C++/etc. source code that demonstrates how DHCP assigns IP addresses almost so flawlessly? Thanks.

Comment: This is *way* too broad. Please see [ask] and then narrow down your question. Also, requesting assistance locating off-site resources is **explicitly** off-topic. Please take some time to go through the site [tour] and [help] to learn more about how things work around here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will probably be different for different DHCP servers, and should be documented for the particular DHCP server you are using. For example, a web search finds at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831538(v=ws.11).aspx

If a client request matches the conditions of a policy for which a specific IP address range is associated, the server will assign the first free IP address from the range as determined by the rule. If a policy is associated with multiple address ranges, the server will assign IP addresses by first attempting to assign an IP from the lowest address range. If no IP addresses are available to use from the lower address range, the server will then look for a free IP address from the higher address ranges. If no IP addresses are free from any of the address ranges associated with the policy, the server will process the next matched policy as defined by the processing order.